# table of contents problem

Tags: table-of-contents

I have the following code, the problem is that table of contents is not working, it does not use section titles as it should instead there is only a "Contents" title. How to fix that?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article} 

\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig} 
\usepackage[margin=0.98in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathpazo}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\linespread{1.15} 

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{\textbf{#1.}} 
\renewcommand{\@listI}{\itemsep=0pt} 

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{ 
\begin{flushright} 
{\LARGE\@title} 
\vspace{50pt} 

{\large\@author} 
\\\@date 

\vspace{40pt} 
\end{flushright}
}



\title{\textbf{Lysine Price-Fixing Conspiracy}\\ 
Causes and the aftermath} 

\author{\textsc{aaa}} 

\date{\today} 

\begin{document}

\maketitle 
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section*{Abstract}
Morbi tempor congue porta. Proin semper, leo vitae faucibus dictum, metus mauris lacinia lorem, ac congue leo felis eu tu

\newpage


\vspace{30pt} 


\section*{Introduction}

This statement requires citation \cite{heu}; this one does too 
%------------------------------------------------

\section*{Section Name}

C


\section*{Conclusion}

Fusce in nibh augue. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis is ac blandit eget, dignissim quis nunc.

\begin{enumerate}
\item First numbered list item
\item Second numbered list item
\end{enumerate}

Donec luctus tincidunt mauris, non ultrices ligula aliquam id. Se


\newpage

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografia}

    \bibitem{beaman} Juliusz Beaman, \textit{Morbidity of the Jolly
        function}, Mathematica Absurdica, 117 (1965) 338--9.




\end{thebibliography}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have disabled the entries in the table of contents by using the star form of the `\section` command. Remove the star and specify that sections should not be numbered via counter `secnumdepth`.

Also level `chapter` is not available for class `article`.

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\section{Abstract}
Morbi tempor congue porta. Proin semper, leo vitae faucibus dictum, metus
mauris lacinia lorem, ac congue leo felis eu tu

\section{Introduction}
\section{Section Name}
\section{Conclusion}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Bibliografia}

    \bibitem{beaman} Juliusz Beaman, \textit{Morbidity of the Jolly
        function}, Mathematica Absurdica, 117 (1965) 338--9.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Adding dots for section level in table of contents

The following example patches `\l@section`, which is responsible for formatting the section entries in the table of contents.
The dot setting is taken from `\@dottedtocline`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\l@section{%
  \nobreak\hfil\nobreak
}{%
  \nobreak
  \leaders\hbox{%
    $\m@th \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep mu$%
  }%
  \hfill
  \nobreak
}{}{\errmessage{\noexpand\l@section could not be patched}}
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\section{Abstract}
Morbi tempor congue porta. Proin semper, leo vitae faucibus dictum, metus
mauris lacinia lorem, ac congue leo felis eu tu

\section{Introduction}
\section{Section Name}
\subsection{Subsection Name}
\section{Conclusion}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Bibliografia}

    \bibitem{beaman} Juliusz Beaman, \textit{Morbidity of the Jolly
        function}, Mathematica Absurdica, 117 (1965) 338--9.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with dots]

Comment: thank you, but i would like to have dots in table of contents (Between title of the section and number of the page). How to do that?