# Lyx Table of Contents not being generated

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx

Here is a minimal working example as exported from Lyx

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\title{Test}

\author{Me}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents{}

\part*{Part 1}
\section*{Sec 1}
Test
\section*{Sec 2}
Test
\end{document}
```

I have used a TOC before when using TexWorks etc and know that the compiler has to run several times. How do I get Lyx to generate the TOC?
Thanks

Comment: You need to use numbered sections, parts, etc. The unnumbered ones you are using (in the LaTeX code the `*` after `\part` etc. denotes that it is unnumbered) do not show up in the ToC.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Answering (or closing rather as a duplicate (which most likely it is!)?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Answered, though duping would have been an option (see comment on the answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unnumbered headings (part, section, etc.) are not placed in the table of contents, so you need to use the numbered equivalents instead. In the LaTeX code, the `*` after `\part`, `\section` etc. indicates that it is an unnumbered heading, and the same `*` is used in LyX.

On the other hand. If you don't want any of the headings to be numbered, but still show up in the ToC, go to *Document --> Settings --> Numbering & TOC*, and drag the *Numbering* slider all the way to the left. This will hide the number from the various headings.

[image]

In LaTeX terms, this adds `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}` to the preamble, which turns off numbering for all sectioning levels. (Actually, `-1` would have been sufficient I think, don't know why LyX makes it `-2`.) The different levels of headings are numbered from -1 (part) to 5 (subparagraph), and the `secnumdepth` counter determines which levels will have numbers displayed. Similarly there is a `tocdepth` counter which determines which levels are placed in the ToC. In LyX, the value of this counter is also adjusted in *Numbering & TOC* in the document settings.

A small LaTeX code example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section*{A}
Unnumbered, not in ToC.

\section{B}
Numbered, in ToC.

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\section{C}

Numbered, but number hidden, in ToC.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is kind of a duplicate of [table of contents problem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/246572), but due to the LyX angle I added this answer.